# Lua and multicast

Tags: python, lua, udp, multicast

I'm trying to convert some code from python to lua.

The relevant bit in python is:

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.settimeout(3)
sock.bind(('239.0.3.138', 3935))
mreq = struct.pack("=4sl", socket.inet_aton('239.0.3.138'), socket.INADDR_ANY)
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)
print( sock.recv(1500) )
```

What I'm trying to do in Lua is:

```
udp = socket.udp()
udp:setpeername( '239.0.3.138','3935')
udp:settimeout(3.0)
udp:setoption( "ip-add-membership", { multiaddr="239.0.3.138", interface="*"  } ) 
print( udp:receive(1500) )
```

I'm not that familiar neither with Lua nor with networking. I'm just trying to learn a bit. Any clue about what am I missing?

The Lua code is reaching the timeout.

Comment: Just a guess: try `udp:receivefrom()`.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff is predictably subtle, leaving breadcrumbs on a path to enlightment...

Answer (score 0):

Luasocket repository has examples for [sending](https://github.com/diegonehab/luasocket/blob/master/samples/mcsend.lua) and [receiving](https://github.com/diegonehab/luasocket/blob/master/samples/mclisten.lua) messages over UDP. The code in the example looks similar to yours and it's using `receivefrom` as Egor suggested. Although since you use `setpeername`, `receive` should work as well [according to the documentation](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/udp.html#setpeername).